# MySQL Database doesn't show changes made in webapp

Tags: mysql, symfony, crud, one-to-many

I'm working on a boardgame library in Symfony. However I must add I'm pretty new to Symfony and also still a rookie in coding itself. Every boardgame can have multiple items. I made a Boardgame entity and an Item entity via the maker in Symfony with a OneToMany relationship. I wanted to make an Add button to add more items of a single boardgame, however, the items don't get added to my MySQL database, but do add up on screen in the app itself. I can't seem to pinpoint what the problem is as all my other functions in the Controller so far who are quite similar seem to work fine.

This is the code snippet for the Add item function included in my BoardgameController:

```
#[Route('/boardgames/add-item/{id}', name: 'app_boardgame_add_item', methods: ['POST'])]
public function addItem(Boardgame $boardgame): RedirectResponse
{
    $item = new Item();
    $item->setBoardgame($boardgame)
        ->setPresent(true);

    $boardgame->addItem($item);
    $this->entityManager->persist($item);
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_boardgame');
}
```

This is the code snippet for the Add button in my template:

```
<td>
      <form action="{{ path('app_boardgame_add_item', {'id': boardgame.id}) }}" method="post">
                  <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
</td>
```

This is my Boardgame entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BoardgameRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BoardgameRepository::class)]
class Boardgame
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?float $ratingBoardgameGeek = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'boardgame', targetEntity: Item::class)]
    private Collection $items;

    #[ORM\Column(nullable: true)]
    private ?int $releaseYear = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $imagePath = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $gameType = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->items = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRatingBoardgameGeek(): ?float
    {
        return $this->ratingBoardgameGeek;
    }

    public function setRatingBoardgameGeek(?float $ratingBoardgameGeek): self
    {
        $this->ratingBoardgameGeek = $ratingBoardgameGeek;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Item>
     */
    public function getItems(): Collection
    {
        return $this->items;
    }

    public function addItem(Item $item): self
    {
        if (!$this->items->contains($item)) {
            $this->items->add($item);
            $item->setBoardgame($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeItem(Item $item): self
    {
        if ($this->items->removeElement($item)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($item->getBoardgame() === $this) {
                $item->setBoardgame(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getItemsAvailable(): int
    {
        $itemsAvailable = 0;

        foreach ($this->items as $item) {
            if ($item->isPresent()) {
                $itemsAvailable++;
            }
        }

        return $itemsAvailable;
    }

    public function getReleaseYear(): ?int
    {
        return $this->releaseYear;
    }

    public function setReleaseYear(?int $releaseYear): self
    {
        $this->releaseYear = $releaseYear;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImagePath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imagePath;
    }

    public function setImagePath(string $imagePath): self
    {
        $this->imagePath = $imagePath;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getGameType(): ?string
    {
        return $this->gameType;
    }

    public function setGameType(string $gameType): self
    {
        $this->gameType = $gameType;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

This is my Item entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ItemRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ItemRepository::class)]
class Item
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'items')]
    private ?Boardgame $boardgame = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $present = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getBoardgame(): ?Boardgame
    {
        return $this->boardgame;
    }

    public function setBoardgame(?Boardgame $boardgame): self
    {
        $this->boardgame = $boardgame;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isPresent(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->present;
    }

    public function setPresent(bool $present): self
    {
        $this->present = $present;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Finally this is my ItemType form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Item;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('present')
            ->add('boardgame', null, ['class' => Boardgame::class])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Item::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This is my first time asking a question here, so if you need more info or I'm doing something wrong, please let me know!:)

Regarding trying to solve it myself I tried:

- Checking if the route is configured correctly
- Checking the form submission
- Made sure that the boardgames with the ID also existed in the database
- Refreshed the database
- Looked up online for similar issues to no avail

Comment: Hello! I guess you miss to add cascade persist on your entity relationship. In your Item entity and $boardGame you must add this #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'items', cascade: ['persist'])]. I will let you find the appropriate doc to check the right way to write it :)